# Does a MySQL VIEW is belogs to a user who created it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Consider a senario where a user (ex:user1) create a VIEW(ex: WORKS_ON1) using two mysql tables(ex: EMPLOYEE, WORKS_ON).Then that user lost the ALL Pervilages of those two tables.(ex: ADMIN Revoking ALL pervilages from user1 of accessing EMPLOYEE, WORKS_ON.). my questions are?

1) Can user1 access the view ( WORKS_ON1) that he created? (seems like he can't) why?

2) Why can't even root( user who has all privilages) access that VIEW(WORKS_ON1)?

Comment: it maybe because `user1` created the view which makes him the owner of the view. If he did not `grant` privileges on the `view` to other users, they can not access it. Because `user1` lost his privileges on the view's underlying tables, he can't access it either. From the documentation .. `The standard says that the definer of the view, which is the same as the owner of the view's schema, gets applicable privileges on the view (for example, SELECT) and may grant them. MySQL has no concept of a schema “owner”, so MySQL adds a clause to identify the definer.`

Comment: does  user1 need to grant privileges explicitly to other users? The root is the user who created user1 in the first place, does root need the permission of user1 to access a view that user1 created?